# Sound lost in 16.04 LTS on Asus x556uf laptop

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an Asus Laptop and last night my audio died off randomly. I reinstalled Linux but it still has no audio!

**Tried**: Unmuted all in *alsamixer*, selected *Analog Stereo Duplex* in *pavucontrol*, reinstalled alsamixer and pulseaudio and checked speech-dispatcher.

Running ***sudo alsa force-reload*** gives this output:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-soc-sst-ipc 
snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-match snd-soc-core 
snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek 
snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core 
snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer 
(failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek 
snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep 
snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc 
snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-sst-match 
snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-hdmi 
snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel 
snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
```

Running ***aplay -l*** gives output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC255 Analog [ALC255 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Running ***sudo lspci -v*** gives:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
Memory at df328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Comment: I have edited it, @K7AAY. Please help.

Comment: I have tried headphones too, no sound. Just some noise.

Comment: What happens when you boot from a LiveUSB; do you have sound then?

Comment: No, no sound even then.

Comment: Understand the sound failure occurs on both internal speakers, and the analog audio out jack. Have you checked HDMI out? Also, please try a different LiveUSB version, such as 18.04 LTS.